# Jest Vuejs Test - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I started first time to test my vuejs application. In my application I have a list of clients, and when you click on client, you go to that clients page, which I am try to test right now. But my test fails before I started with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

created() {
   this.clientid = this.$route.params.id;
                                   ^
   this.getClient();
}
```

I tried to set this into my test:

```
describe('Client', () => {
    it('should mount Client', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(Client, {
        data: () => ({
          route: {
            params: {
              id: ''
            }
          },
        }),
      });
      expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    });
  });
```

Can you help me understand how to give this params a value through the test?

Answer (score 2):

There has been many different answers on the net, but the for the vue1. This worked for me:

```
describe('Client', () => {
  it('should mount Client', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Client, {
      global: {
        mocks: {
          $route: {params: { id: ""}},
        }
      }
    })
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```